# $X$ is a metric space, $S\subseteq X$ and $a$ is an isolated point of $S$. Then $a \in\partial S$ iff $a$ is not an isolated point of $X$.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

I am trying to prove the following statement:

> $X$ is a metric space, $S\subseteq X$ and $a$ is an isolated point of $S$. Then $a \in\partial S$ iff $a$ is not an isolated point of $X$.

*Proof Attempt:*

1. $(\Rightarrow)$. If $a\in\partial S$, then a is not an isolated point of $X$.

We prove the contrapositive of this statement. Suppose $a$ is an isolated point of $X$. Then $\operatorname{dist}(a,X\setminus\{a\})>0$. Since $a$ is an isolated point of $S$, $a\in S$ and we have $S^c=X\setminus S\subseteq X\setminus\{a\}$ and so $0<\operatorname{dist}(a,X\setminus\{a\})\leq \operatorname{dist}(a,X\setminus S)=\operatorname{dist}(a,S^c)$. Thus $\operatorname{dist}(a,S^c)>0$ and so $a\notin\partial S$.

2. $(\Leftarrow)$. If $a$ is not an isolated point of $X$, then $a\in\partial S$.

Suppose $a$ is not an isolated point of $X$. Then $a$ is an accumulation point of $X$ because $a\in X$. So $\operatorname{dist}(a,X\setminus \{a\})=0$ and as before, $S^c=X\setminus S\subseteq X\setminus\{a\}$ implies $0=\operatorname{dist}(a,X\setminus\{a\})\leq \operatorname{dist}(a,X\setminus S)=\operatorname{dist}(a,S^c)$ i.e., $\operatorname{dist}(a,S^c)\geq 0$. If $\operatorname{dist}(a,S^c)>0$, since $a\in S$ ($a$ being an isolated point of $S$), we have $S^c=S^c\setminus \{a\}$ and so $\operatorname{dist}(a,S^c\setminus \{a\})>0$, which means that $a$ is also an isolated point of $S^c$, a contradiction. Thus $\operatorname{dist}(a,S^c)=0$, and so $a\in\partial S$.

Is there any mistake in my attempt?

Comment: Suppose $a$ is an isolated point of $X$.Then $\{a\}$ is open in  $X$.But $\{a\}$ doesn't intersect $X\setminus S$ , hence $ a $ can't be in $\partial S$ (contradiction!).

Comment: This is the  same proof but topological in nature.